# AH01276 after update

Tags: apache, passenger

I updated my apache from 2.4.2 to 2.4.23.  I am using passenger.  I did not change my configuration files.  On 2.4.2 it works.  On 2.4.23 I get this error:

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/user-name/app-base/current/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (none) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

I did **not** recompile my passenger module because it is sorta hard but I can if that may be the issue.

Do I need to recompiler my passenger module or is this something that is a configuration issue?  And if it is a configuration issue, I need help figuring out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating to Apache 2.4.23 while running Passenger 4.0.59.  When I started up httpd, Passenger chattered in the server logs and appeared to load ok, but it would not run my Rails app.  I set DirectoryIndex index.html and created an index.html file in the app's public directory and the static page came up instead of the app.  Tried updating to Passenger 4.0.60 and no change.  Updated to 5.0.30 and then the problem finally went away.  Don't know exactly what the problem was and didn't notice anything relevant in the Apache or Passenger change logs.  Using the most recent Apache *and* Passenger seems to reduce the chance of trouble.

Ordinarily you should be able to rebuild Passenger easily by running passenger-install-apache2-module.  Good luck.